# Infimum and supremum of function

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a >0$ and consider function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g(x) = x e^{-ax^2}$. Find infimum and supremum of $g$.$\lim_{a \to 0} x e^{-a x^2} = x$, so we can obtain every value of $\mathbb{R}$. So infimum and supremum are $-\infty$, $+\infty$. Am I right?

Comment: I think you are expected to consider $a$ to be a fixed number, and obtain the inf and sup in terms of $a$.

Comment: Yes, my fault. But what to do then?

Comment: There is a standard way (derivatives) to look for relative maxima and minima.  Then argue these are the absolute maxima and minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the derivative of $g$:
$$
g'(x)=e^{-ax^2}-2ax^2 e^{-ax^2}=(1-2ax^2)e^{-ax^2}.
$$
Since $a$ is positive, the equation $1-2ax^2=0$ has real roots and $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2a}}$. Then find these values:

- $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$
- $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=0$
- $g(1/\sqrt{2a})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2ea}}$: maximum(supremum)
- $g(-1/\sqrt{2a})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2ea}}$: minimum(infimum)